# How to change text to link?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Have data collected from API. I need to convert the text in  mark to URL. Any idea of how to do it with JS and/or TS?

I got:

[image]

My code:

```
  function changeToLink(){
        let tableCells = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('td'));
        var i;    
        var proNo = "PR0";
            
         for (i=0; i<tableCells.length; i++ && isContains == true) {
          var proFromArray = tableCells[i].innerHTML;
          var isContains = proFromArray.includes(proNo);    
          
                   
          if(isContains == true){
            var text = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[i];
               console.log(text);
          }
         }
        
        
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one idea:

```
if(isContains == true){
    var tdElement = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[i];
    tdElement.InnerHtml = "<a href='http://your_link'>Your Link</a>"
}
```

Comment: Oh my! I tried to add innerHTML after [i] --> `var tdElement = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[i].innerHTML = "<a href='http://your_link'>Your Link</a>"` and I get an error. Your solution works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

that function works for me.

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
  var string = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x[1].innerHTML;
  console.log(string);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/adids1221/b5on0Ldh/